# if we had a single file project that contained all the code can we not use the linker?

Tags: c++, c, embedded

**Linker question**:

if I had a file. c that has no includes at all, would we still need a **linker**?

Comment: Yes you do, unless you are planning to reimplement every class, template and function in both the C and the C++ library, by yourself.

Comment: Most likely you'll stil need it.  You need to link to the run time libraries for input and output normally.

Comment: **linker is required** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)

Comment: The object file format is not an ELF/EXE/Whatever. The linker is repsonsible for creating the appropriate executable format.

Comment: you can build it in single simple command: `gcc source.c -o excutableName`.

Comment: Yes.    In a "compile then link" build chain, the compiler typically outputs an object file, which is not in an executable format.   Even if the source file depended on no  header files, the linker is needed to convert the object file to an executable format.   The only difference is that the linker can link together the functions in multiple object files and libraries (e.g. link each point where a function is called to start of the called function) to produce a single executable.

Comment: If you don't use a linker, you will need more than one pass in order to resolve symbols and emit executable code.  There are some patterns in C++ that require reserving space (like the destination of a function call) that can't be resolved until the address of the function is determined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a project, which has no typical C startup code, in which case, you may not even have a `main()`. However, you still need a linker, because the linker creates the required executable file format for the given architecture.

It also will set the entrypoint, where the actual execution starts.
So you can omit the standard libraries, and create a binary, which is completly void of any C functions, but you still need the linker to actually make a runable binary.

The object file format, generated by the compiler, is very different to the executable file format, because it only provides all information, that is required for the linker.

Answer (score 4):

Although the linker is so-named because it links together multiple object files, it performs other functions as well. It may resolve addresses that were left incomplete by the compiler. It produces a program in an executable file format that the system’s program loader can read and load, and that format may differ from that of object modules. Specifics depend on the operating system and build tools.

Further, to have a complete program in one source file, you must provide not just the `main` routine you are familiar with from C and C++ but also the true start of the program, the entry point that the program loader starts execution at, and you must provide implementations for all functions you use in the program, such as invocations of system services via special trap or system-call instructions to read and write data.

Comment: so i take it :
if i made a file.c that included 1- the main function 2-.the body of every single function call i made 3- the startup code that will lead to the main eventually 4-everything that must be included that i don't know   
i would still need the linker to do the job of just transfering the file.obj to file.exe or hex or any thing

Comment: This question and this answer reminded me of [this](https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-to-execute-an-object-file-part-1/) blog post which talks about loading and executing an object file directly. tl;dr: It is possible, but you have to do a lot of things manually, instead of relying on the loader.

Comment: @AliHamdy, IMO this blog post is not to the point, because the very existence, of `parseObject` shows that the linker is inevitable. Tranfering the job of the linker into a custom object parser is just obfuscating this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The linker does more than merely link the files. Check out this resource for more info: [https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Programming_Languages/C%2B%2B/Code/Compiler/Linker#:~:text=The%20linker%20is%20a%20program,translation%20unit%20have%20external%20linkage](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Programming_Languages/C%2B%2B/Code/Compiler/Linker#:%7E:text=The%20linker%20is%20a%20program,translation%20unit%20have%20external%20linkage).

Believe it or not, multiple libraries can be referenced by default. So, even if you don't `#include`a resource, the compiler may have to internally link or reference something outside of the translation unit. There are also redundancies and other considerations that are "eliminated" by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Despite its name the linker is properly a "linker/locater".  It performs two functions - 1) linking object code, 2) determining where in memory the data and code elements exist.

The object code out of the compiler is not "located" even if it has no unresolved links.

Also even if you have the simplest possible valid code:

```
int main(){ return 0; }
```

with *no includes*, the linker will normally implicitly link the C runtime start-up, which is required to do everything necessary before running `main()`.  That may be very little.  On some target such as ARM Cortex-M you can in fact run C code directly from the reset vector so long as you don't assume static initialisation or complete library support.  So it is possible to write the reset code entirely in C, but you probably still need code to initialise the vector table with the reset handler (your C start-up function) and the initial stack pointer.  On Cortex-M that can be done using in-line assembler perhaps, but it is all rather cumbersome and unnecessary and does not forgo the linker.